# How to import C++ code with cmake to eclipse cdt or visual studio?

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake

I want to import the code library https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o as a project in Eclipse C++ and execute it in debug mode putting breakpoints. I am new to c++ programming. I cannot figure out how to set up a new project with existing sources. The project uses cmake for configuring the compilation and dependencies. Do I need any plugin for integrating it in eclipse?

I tried visual studio also. But with no success.

Please help

Comment: cmake can generate a solution for you, it surely can do it for VS, not sure if it can do that for eclipse as well

Comment: If you are new to c++ the only way is to use CMake to generate your Visual Studio project file.

Comment: Please post the error messages you got when you used CMake to generate your Visual Studio project.

Comment: @drescherjm cmake crashes when i try to generate visual studio project

Answer (score 2):

[CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html) support [Visual Studio and Eclipse CDT4 generators](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generators.7.html):

Install cmake and do the configuration in cmake-gui, then use the project files in Visual Studio or Eclipse.

[image: cmake-gui]

Comment: thanks for the answer. For the code I want to import there are some dependencies like the Eigen library. I cannot properly configure it in cmake. Can you tell me what is the right way to do that?